# Java Generics, the type gets lost

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-errors

The following example, although seemingly correct, won't compile (Eclipse Neon 3, Java 1.8):

```
class Test {    

    public static class SomeForm<IF extends SomeForm<IF>> {

    }

    public static class BaseFF<IF extends SomeForm<IF>> {

    }

    public static class AuxFF<IF extends SomeForm<IF>>
            extends BaseFF<IF> {

    }

    public interface Interface<IF extends SomeForm<IF>, FF extends BaseFF<IF>> {
        FF getFF1();        
    }

    public static class ZBaseUnit<IF extends SomeForm<IF>, FF extends BaseFF<IF>>
            implements Interface<IF, FF> {

        @Override
        public FF getFF1() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static class ZMyUnit<IF extends SomeForm<IF>, FF extends AuxFF<IF>>
            extends ZBaseUnit<IF, FF> {

    }

    public static class ZMyCheck<IF extends SomeForm<IF>, U extends ZMyUnit<IF, ?>> {
        U unit;

        void f() {
            BaseFF<IF> ff1 = unit.getFF1();
        }

    }

}
```

Eclipse says (on the line inside f() method):

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? to Test.BaseFF".

However, if I remove the method getFF1 from the interface Interface (and the @Override annotation in the class ZBaseUnit), it compiles. Is there some logic behind this? Intuitively, it seems that FF passed to Interface is the same as FF passed to ZBaseUnit, so there should be no difference...

Also, there is no error if I add the method in ZMyUnit:

```
void f() {
    BaseFF<IF> ff1 = getFF1();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: More interestingly: I'd not assume `ZMyUnit<IF,   ?    > unit;` instead of `U unit;` to compile either, since in both cases you're referring to the same base class. But it compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this verification code to you class

```
public static class GF extends SomeForm<GF> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZMyCheck<GF, ZMyUnit<GF, AuxFF<GF>>> z = new ZMyCheck<>();
    z.unit = new ZMyUnit<>();
    z.f();
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

and use standard JDK command-line tools (`javac` and `java`), then the code will compile and run successfully. The same is true if you use NetBeans (I have no intention to promote NetBeans in any way).

Therefore, the problem is Eclipse-specific. Eclipse has its own built-in compiler and it seems that you've found one of its weaknesses (maybe you need to file a bug report). It is unable to determine that the wildcard `?` is, in fact, referring to the type that extends `AuxFF<IF>` (and, therefore, `BaseFF<IF>`). You need to indicate this explicitly:

```
public static class ZMyCheck<IF extends SomeForm<IF>,
    U extends ZMyUnit<IF, ? extends AuxFF<IF>>> {...}
```

Then all will compile and run swimmingly.

Comment: This does a good job of identifying the nature of the problem, but it's a little light on explaining why the JDK's compiler is the one that is right, and not Eclipse's.

Comment: @JohnBollinger JDK's compiler is right because it is the reference implementation of Java compiler. Moreover, OP started the question saying that the code is **seemingly correct** (and I agree with that) adding later a few reasons why this particular error looks strange. Obviously, if `ZMyUnit` has a type bound for the second parameter, then this bound should also be imposed on the wildcard at the bound for `U` parameter of `ZMyCheck` class.

Comment: No, @JohnMcClane.  Any Java compiler's correctness is a function of its conformance to the Java Language Specification and Java VM Specification.  That includes the JDK's compiler, which indeed has had its share of bugs over the years.  It is entirely possible for that compiler to be the buggy one.  As for your "Obviously, ...", that's certainly a *plausible* argument, but its plausibility is ultimately irrelevant unless the argument is consistent with the JLS.  I'm not saying it *isn't* consistent, but that analysis is non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you @JohnMcClane! I didn't think that anything would change if I explicitly specify the type for "?" wildcard, but now I see I was wrong. Also thanks for verifying that my code is correct from the view point of java/javac.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to class `ZMyCheck` and the variable initialization within ...

> ```
>     public static class ZMyCheck<IF extends SomeForm<IF>, U extends ZMyUnit<IF, ?>> {
>         U unit;
>
>         void f() {
>             BaseFF<IF> ff1 = unit.getFF1();
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

... the correctness ultimately comes down to the type of the expression `unit.getFF1()`, and whether that type is a subtype of `BaseFF<IF>`.  The type of that expression is a function of the type of instance variable `unit`, which, as a result of type erasure, is interpreted as the upper bound of type variable `U`, that is, `ZMyUnit<IF, ?>`.

With respect to the type of `unit.getFF1()`, then, the JLS specifies that

> The types of the fields, methods, and constructors [of a type] are the types of the fields, methods, and constructors in the capture conversion of [that type].

([JLS 10, 4.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.2))

We therefore need to determine the capture conversion of type `ZMyUnit<IF, ?>`, as specified in [section 5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).  The specification gets fairly technical here, but the bottom line is that the upper bound of `ZMyUnit`'s second type parameter factors in, so that there is a capture conversion to type `ZMyUnit<IF, AuxFF<IF>>`.  Interpreted according to that type, method `getFF1()` returns type `AuxFF<IF>`, which is subject to a widening reference conversion to type `BaseFF<IF>`, and that is what is needed.

Thus, as @JohnMcClane also answered, Eclipse's compiler is incorrect in rejecting the code presented.  Adding an appropriate upper bound to the wildcard seems to work around the issue without changing the semantics of the code with respect to the JLS.